# How is a statement like let Select = Seq.filter compiled to CIL?

Tags: f#, inline, cil

I wonder how a statement like

```
 let Select = Seq.filter
```

is compiled into CIL: Does the compiler inline the call to Seq.filter?
There is an indication for this assumption because the compiler complains:

```
 let inline Select = Seq.filter
 error FS0832: Only functions may be marked 'inline'
```

Comment: Get Chocolatey, then `cinst ilspy`, Windows, `ILS`, Enter and you'll have your answer without any indirection

Comment: In F# `inline` is used with functions parameterized by type parameters. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd548047.aspx

Comment: @EugeneFotin - that's typical but not necessary; if you want a non-generic function to be inlined at usage sites there's nothing stopping you from doing so.

Comment: I just wondered if one of you just knew the answer right away. I didn't look at CIL code since years, and I not sure whether I would draw the correct conclusion from reading it.  By the way: I wrote "Select" because I am helping a friend to write something looking like MATHEMATICA, and he has chosen the uppercase. Then I picked one of the lines as an example...

Comment: @SiegfriedStephan The point is ILSpy will give you VB or C# (or IL). (And despite your question being valid, I still think you shouldnt think of loading ILSpy as hard or slow in any way)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that your inference is logical - the compiler is not saying, "You can't inline this because it's already being inlined", it's saying, "You can only inline a (syntactic) function" (that is, there need to be syntactic arguments, like `let inline select f = Seq.filter f`).

Generally, it's an implementation detail whether the compiler inlines a definition, and the behavior could change depending on whether you're compiling in debug or release mode (there are exceptions, such as definitions which could be side-effecting, which must not be inlined in order to preserve semantics, such as `let f = printfn "blah"; fun x -> x`, where `"blah"` must only be printed exactly once).  If you want to see what a particular version of the F# compiler does, just use ildasm to disassemble your compiled code and take a look.  But also keep in mind that the JIT engine may inline things even if they're not inline in IL, so it's probably not important either way.

Also, as a minor stylistic note, keep in mind that values and functions in modules are typically bound to camelCase identifiers (so `select`, not `Select`), while members of types follow the normal .NET naming style.